# LibGDX: Do I have to dispose a texture if I load it from AssetManager?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures, scene2d

```
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

manager.load("texture1", Texture.class); 
manager.load("texture2", Texture.class);
manager.load("texture3", Texture.class);
//And so on...
```

And then I load it from another screen, do I still have to dispose it? Or manager does it when I call `manager.clear`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call `dispose` directly on a `Texture` loaded by an `AssetManager`, they are disposed the the `AssetManager` is cleared or disposed or if you call `unload` on the `AssetManager` and pass the `Texture`.

The reason you shouldn't dispose assets from an `AssetManager` is that they can be shared between many other assets (two fonts may use the same texture for example) and the `AssetManager` tracks this by reference  counting them so that even if you call `unload` for a texture it will not get unloaded until you also unload the dependant assets.

Comment: Oh, in my game i have a bullet entity, when it dies i call dispose on the texture, that's why it seems like a black square after it, thanks!

Comment: @Asaltaviejas Glad I could help.